# Prove subsets of cartesian product are independent events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Given $(\Omega_1,p_1)$ and $(\Omega_2,p_2)$ finite probability spaces, $A_1\subset\Omega_1$, $A_2\subset\Omega_2$, I want to prove
$$ \mathbb{P}((A_1\times \Omega_2) \cap(\Omega_1 \times A_2)) = \mathbb{P}(A_1\times\Omega_2)\mathbb{P}(\Omega_1\times A_2) $$
i.e. $(A_1\times \Omega_2)$ and $(\Omega_1\times A_2)$ are independent events.

My attempt is to simplify the left side to $\sum_{\omega \in (A_1\times \Omega_2) \cap(\Omega_1 \times A_2)} p_1(\omega_1) p_2(\omega_2)$ but the I don't know how to rearrange the right side correctly (RHS $=\sum_{\omega\in A_1\times \Omega_2}p_1(\omega_1)p_2(\omega_2) \sum_{\omega\in \Omega_1\times A_2}p_1(\omega_1)p_2(\omega_2)$

Answer (score 1):

$\Omega$ and $\mathsf{P}$ here are $\Omega_1\times \Omega_2$ and $p_1\times p_2$. Then for $A\subset \Omega_1$ and $B\subset \Omega_2$,
$$
\mathsf{P}((A\times \Omega_2)\cap (\Omega_1\times B))=\mathsf{P}(A\times B)=p_1(A)p_2(B)=\mathsf{P}(A\times \Omega_2)\mathsf{P}(\Omega_1\times B).
$$